# Showing that all matrix norms satisfy the scalar property

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, normed-spaces

How can I show that all matrix norms satisfy the following property (where $α$ is a scalar):

$$\| α A \| = | α | \| A \|,\ ∀α ∈ R$$

This is for matrix norms defined in terms of $\| A \| = \max ( \|Ax\|/\|x\|)$

Is this approach correct?

$$\| α A \| = \max \frac{\| (α A) x \| }{ \| x \|}$$

$$\| α A \| = \max \frac{ \| α (Ax) \| }{ \| x \|}$$

$$\| α A \| = \| α \| \max \frac{\| Ax \| }{ \| x \|}$$

$$\| α A \| = | α | \max \frac{\| Ax \| }{ \| x \|}$$

Comment: Yes, it is correct, only $||\alpha||$ should be replaced by $|\alpha|$.

Comment: Is it proper to take ∥α∥ out of the max ∥α(Ax)∥/∥x∥ fraction without writing ∥α∥ over ∥x∥ ?

Comment: $\alpha$ is a scalar, so yes.

Comment: @stevetronix : Notice that when you write \max instead of max, there are at least three effects: (1) it is not italicized; (2) it has proper spacing in things like $a\max b$ (with space to the right and left of $\max$) and in things like $a\max(b)$ (with space to the left that does _not_ appear on the right); and (3) in a displayed setting, as opposed to an inline setting, subscripts appear directly below $\max$, as in $\displaystyle \max_{x\in\mathcal X} f(x) \vphantom{\frac\int\int}$, with $x\in\mathcal X$ in the subscript. And it's standard usage and I've edited accordingly. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematicians might phrase this question by asking how to show that all matrix norms, defined by $\| A \| = \max ( \|Ax\|/\|x\|)$, are actually norms, in the sense usually stated in the definition of a norm of a vector space.  Except that this addresses only one aspect of that.

For norms of vectors, you know that for every scalar $\alpha$ and every vector $x$ you have $\|\alpha x\| = |\alpha|\|x\|$.  Then you have
$$
\| \alpha A \| = \max\frac{\|(\alpha A)x\|}{\|x\|} = \max \frac{ \| \alpha (Ax) \| }{ \| x \|} = \max \frac{|\alpha|\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}
$$
These steps you know are true because of **definitions:** (1) the definition of norm of a linear operator; (2) the definition of multiplication of a linear operator by a scalar; (3) the definition of norm on a vector space.  Each of the three "equals" signs corresponds to one of those definitions, in just that order.

But next we ask how to justify this:
$$
\max \frac{|\alpha|\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}\  \overset{\Large\text{?}} =\  |\alpha|\max\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}.
$$
There is an $x$ for which the maximum on the left side is achieved (how we know that is another question of possible interest); call it $x_0$.  Therefore
$$
\text{For all vectors $x$, we have } \frac{|\alpha|\|Ax\|}{\|x\|} \le \frac{|\alpha|\|Ax_0\|}{\|x_0\|}.
$$
Hence
$$
\text{For all vectors $x$, we have }\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|} \le \frac{\|Ax_0\|}{\|x_0\|}.
$$
And from that we get
$$
\max \frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|} = \frac{\|Ax_0\|}{\|x_0\|}.
$$
So
$$
\|A\| = \frac{\|Ax_0\|}{\|x_0\|}.
$$
And we know that
$$
\frac{\|(\alpha A)x_0\|}{\|x_0\|} = |\alpha|\frac{\|Ax_0\|}{\|x_0\|} = |\alpha| \|A\|.
$$